# Can't install Sails.js, installation failure

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

When I try to install Sails.js, I get:

> npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
>   npm WARN deprecated guid@0.0.12: Please use node-uuid instead. It is much better.
>
> ws@0.4.32 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

the console hangs right here and never does anything else.

I tried uninstalling all node_modules and reinstalling an earlier version:

sudo rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear
sudo npm install npm@1.4.23 -g
sudo npm install sails -g

Still the exact same problem. Anyone else run into this and have a solution?

Comment: In which platform are you using sails? Mac, or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Mac OSX 10.7.5

I simply updated to 10.9.5 and followed the normal installation procedures, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. A better solution is to use:

```
npm -g install npm
```

This will install the latest npm version

Answer (score 0):

A way of handling this, as I've seen it, is by installing the latest version of NPM:

```
npm install -g npm@1.4.24
```

And you may have to remove the Grunt Cli first done like so:

```
npm -g remove grunt-cli
```

The guys running Sails have also addressed this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2124

Answer (score 0):

If you use apt-get or any other to install npm fist, then you must remove it with apt-get then use the `sudo npm install -g npm@1.4.24` to install the 1.4 version